# Function not ending correctly after recursive loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, return

I am trying to build a copy cat of the game risk. I have a while loop which says while the attack isn't finished do something. Then I ask the user to type in either 'end turn' to end turn or 'continue' to recursively call the attack function again. The problem is after the user types in attack a few times and then 'end turn' the turn doesn't end rather it starts from the beginning or the function again. I would greatly appreciate an expert eye to look at my code and see what I am missing, thanks in advance.

```
public void attackOrSkip(Player player,Player[] playerArray, int playerId) {
        boolean attackFinished = false;
        int numUnitsAttackWith = 0;
        int defenceArmiesNumber =0;
        displayString(makeLongName(player) + ": Type 'attack' to attack or 'skip' to skip your turn...");
        String command = commandPanel.getCommand();
        displayString(PROMPT + command);
        if(command.equals("skip") ||command.equals("skip ") ||command.equals("s")) {
            return;
        }else if (command.equals("attack") ||command.equals("attack ")){
            displayString(PROMPT + command);
            //while the attack isn't finished
            while(attackFinished == false) {
                
                //get the country the user is attacking
                int countryAttackingFrom=countryFromCheck(playerId,player);
                //get the country to attack
                int countryToAttack = countryToCheck(player);
                //get the player who we are attacking
                int occupierPlayer =board.getOccupier(countryToAttack);
                
                
                if ((board.getNumUnits(countryAttackingFrom)) < 2) {
                    displayString("You dont have enough units on this country to make an attack!");
                    attackOrSkip(player, playerArray, playerId);
                    break;
                    }
                //if the country is adjacent to another one then you can attack else no
                else if(isAdjacent(countryAttackingFrom,countryToAttack)) {
                    
                    //check the number of unit to attack with
                    numUnitsAttackWith =numUnitsCheckerAttack(player,countryAttackingFrom);
                    //check the number of unit to defend with
                    defenceArmiesNumber = numUnitsCheckerDefence(player,countryToAttack);
                    
                    //roll the dice
                    player.rollDice(numUnitsAttackWith);
                    playerArray[occupierPlayer].rollDice(defenceArmiesNumber);
                    
                    //display the roll results
                    displayString(makeLongName(player) + "Rolled: "+printDie(player));
                    displayString(makeLongName(playerArray[occupierPlayer]) + "Rolled: "+printDie(playerArray[occupierPlayer]));
                    
                    }
                    displayString(makeLongName(player) + ": 'end turn' or 'continue'");
                    command = commandPanel.getCommand();
                    displayString(PROMPT + command);
                    if(command.equals("end turn")||command.equals("end turn ") ||command.equals("endturn")||command.equals("endturn ") ||command.equals("end")) {
                        attackFinished = true;
                        return;
                    }else if(command.equals("attack") ||command.equals("attack ")){
//                      break;
                    }else if(command.equals("continue") ||command.equals("continue ") ||command.equals("con")){
                        attackOrSkip(player,playerArray,playerId);
                    }else {
                        return;
                    }
                }else {
                    displayString(makeLongName(player) + ": ERROR, not adjacent countries");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, have you tried printing something after attackFinished is set to true? Does it get there?

Comment: @Nina yes I have tried printing something after attackFinished is set to true, it does print something, so it does reach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - as currently written - every time you call attackOrSkip within the method - you end up 1 level lower in the stack - with a new set of variables -

```
   attackFinished, numUnitsAttackWith, defenceArmiesNumber
```

When you leave the recursion (i.e. via a return) you end up with simple variables as they were before you enter the recursive call - remember Java is Call By Value (even though you can pass in references to objects, you get a value (the current value of the variable reference when called ... and changing the reference to point at a different object doesn't change the callers reference).

SO, without looking to see whether you have done the correct algorithm - I would guess that if you made the method return type a boolean and returned the status instead of nothing, you could update attackFinished and the right thing might happen..

e.g. change all the

```
return;
```

to

```
return attackFinished;
```

AND change all the places where you call

```
attackOrSkip(....)
```

to set attack finished based on what the method return

```
attackFinished = attackOrSkip(....)
```

OR - you can pass in an extra parameter - attackFinished - in a [Holder (an example of the concept)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Holder.html) object - again the reference can't change, but you can go attackFinished.value = true (and it will then be the same the whole way out the stack as you drop out of the recursion).